# Convert Map<String, Object> from JSON

Tags: java, json

I'm currently writing a Spring based webservice application, where the result of the service call are supposed to be sent using a rather generic class `ActionReply`. This class contains a `private Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();` where the objects, that are retrieved from a database can be stored. Now the value can be actually any kind of class, but mostly a subclass of my base class `BaseObject`. The problem I'm facing now is that the returned JSON string when I try to get `Locale` objects stored in that map as value looks like this:

```
reply: <200,{"parameters":{"DATA":["de_DE"]},"successful":true,"errorMessage":null,"subsequentContext":null},{Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8], Transfer-Encoding=[chunked], Date=[Sun, 09 Dec 2018 13:15:21 GMT]}>So
```

So basically that's fine, however the locale object is interpreted as String, which seems normal, because there is no information about the `Locale` class in the JSON string. So my question is, how can I pass that information or what do I have to do when creating from/to the Map that I get `Locale` objects and not `String` objects?

Thanks!

Comment: As I understood your map contains different type of objects? In that case you can't really specify the parsing ahead. If it is a class hierarchy there is various ways that can be done, assuming you are using jackson under the hood. Also please specify your class hierarchy if it is possible. thanks.

Comment: Yes the map can contain basically any kind of object. And my problem is how to create / parse the JSON string. And yes I'm using Jackson

Comment: It all boils down to this question: how can I parse the part `{"DATA":["de_DE"]}` from this JSON string `{"parameters":{"DATA":["de_DE"]},"successful":true,"errorMessage":null,"subsequentContext":null}` into a `Map<String, ArrayList<Locale>>`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not following you properly, but if you get the Locale on a String and you want the Locale object, you have to do something like this:

```
Locale myLocale = new Locale(myRetrievedLocaleString);
```

In the other side, it seems you are not getting a valid JSON object, however if you just need the `locale` and you cannot extract it, then do something like this:

```
String jsonLocale = response.substring(0,32) + "}";
```

That way you will get a valid json on a String, now you'll be able convert it successfully to a JSON object and extract the locale object.

Comment: The problem is that when Spring sends the data back to the client, it transforms the objects into JSON, but since the objects are stored as values in a `Map<String, Object>` it doesn't generate the JSON properly for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution based on JSONPath:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

The following code snippet works fine for me:

```
public static Object extractParametersData(Type type, String json)
{
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    HashMap<String, JSONArray> data = JsonPath.read(json, "$.parameters");

    return gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(data.get("DATA")), type);
}
```